# MySQL Match...Against vs. nulls?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query that uses left joins like so:

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, a.date_created, a.contact_id, a.role_id,
  c.first_name, c.middle_initial, c.last_name, c.email, r.role
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN contacts AS c ON a.contact_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN roles AS r ON a.role_id = r.id
WHERE ( MATCH (a.username, c.first_name, c.middle_initial, c.last_name, c.email) 
  AGAINST ('searchTerm*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )
```

Problem is, there are accounts (a.id) that have no corresponding contact (c.id) or role (r.id), so when joined that information comes up null (I'm guessing).

When that happens I get back results that don't match the search term no matter what (on top of the normal results), and they are all the ones that have nulls filled in by the join.

I've tried different kinds of joins, and I've looked on the internet, but I have yet to find something that specifically addresses this problem.  I think it will be useful to others as I can see this coming up in other domains.

So, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: tried ISNULL(<column>, <replace value>)?

Comment: I just tried ISNULL(c.first_name, 0) and I recieved #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'  I'm using MySQL 5.1

Comment: I think you want to try IFNULL :)

Comment: I tried that too, but IFNULL didn't work out either.  Sorry I posted below it was solved, but it's not.  The following still produces the same problem: SELECT a.id, a.username, COALESCE(c.first_name, '') FROM accounts AS a LEFT JOIN contacts AS c ON a.contact_id = c.id WHERE ( MATCH (a.username, c.first_name) AGAINST ('searchTerm*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `NULLS` with emtpy strings, then you'll not get any spurious matches. Just match against `COALESCE(c.email, '')` (etc.), instead of just the field.

`COALESCE` will return its first parameter, unless it is NULL, then it will return the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the information, that helps quite a bit.  Also see my answer below as well.  That information in your answer is also very useful thanks!

Comment: I tried that, see above comment, and it didn't work.  I finally just decided to design the system differently to work around it.  Thanks for the effort and attention.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, guys, I noticed something I thought was an answer but isn't:  When I put r.role into the matching clause the problem cleared up.  To be honest I don't quite understand the logic but I understand that that's what was making additional records come up because that field was being asked for without a filter.

Unfortunately it remains unsolved.  Sorry for the premature answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not solved, I'm still getting the same problem when I run this query:

Comment: SELECT a.id, a.username, COALESCE(c.first_name, '')
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN contacts AS c ON a.contact_id = c.id
WHERE ( MATCH (a.username, c.first_name) 
  AGAINST ('searchTerm*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )